# Transition on onmouseover / onmouseout is not working?

Tags: css, transition

How can i get the ease-in-out to work without changing the html code?
http://jsfiddle.net/68ojLg6p/

```
<img class="transition-img" 
onmouseover="this.src='http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-ISjKMLTnaTQ/Ty-USX-J1uI/AAAAAAAAC_0/YB6MUMflRmg/s400/ferrari+_car_wallpapers.jpg'" 
onmouseout="this.src='http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-vAbVucAOQXA/TWPq-p9hPEI/AAAAAAAAAjQ/wVABlnpN6xE/s400/2011-cars-images-audi-r8-tdi-le-mans-04.jpg'" 
src="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-vAbVucAOQXA/TWPq-p9hPEI/AAAAAAAAAjQ/wVABlnpN6xE/s400/2011-cars-images-audi-r8-tdi-le-mans-04.jpg" alt="" height="300" width="400">

css:
 .transition-img:hover {
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
 -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
 transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
 }
```

Comment: You can't use css to transition javascript...

Comment: like moose said above. [This](http://jsfiddle.net/TheBanana/68ojLg6p/1/) is as close as you are gonna get...

Answer (score -1):

CSS Transitions will not work with javascript. If you want to use transitions you need to handle your images on the CSS side, see below.

```css
.transition-img {
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  background-image: url('http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-vAbVucAOQXA/TWPq-p9hPEI/AAAAAAAAAjQ/wVABlnpN6xE/s400/2011-cars-images-audi-r8-tdi-le-mans-04.jpg');
}
.transition-img:hover {
  background-image: url('http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-ISjKMLTnaTQ/Ty-USX-J1uI/AAAAAAAAC_0/YB6MUMflRmg/s400/ferrari+_car_wallpapers.jpg');
}
```

```html
<img class="transition-img" alt="" height="300" width="400">
```